# git - squash - rebase - master history concerns

Tags: git, github

I'm a bit anxious about the rebase command. So much so that I've really procrastinated on finishing up this pull request implementing gyroscope functionality for libGDX. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/3361

If you take a look at the commits, I committed, early and often. Then I synced up, committed some more. Now I'm going to have to sync again, test everything before they accept this pull request.

So, there is a spattering of commits interlaced with merges, etc.  It's a mess, I think.
The maintainer wants me to squash my commits into one. Makes sense.  Though, this is where my naivete kicks in full force.

Is rebase only going to affect**my commits**?  Or is there the possibility of overwriting all of the project history by rebasing in my branch and merging?

Should I just start over, check out master, make all the same changes, and make another pull request?

Comment: Rebasing only changes the history of the branch you're rebasing.

Comment: So, could I rebase the entire branch down to one commit, expecting that will not change the history of master once it's merged?  Or, do I need to squash each of my commits into a single commit?

Comment: It won't change the history of the master, but it will change the "presence" of the master. Carefully resolve all conflicts during rebasing.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what "presence" is.  I did some googling, but still not sure of it's definition.  Conflict resolution comes when I merge upstream changes into the branch, no?  Rebasing will only erase the history.  Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, rebasing changes the history, merge changes the master. Conflicts can happen during rebasing.

Comment: As long as you didn't fully understand what rebase does and how it works, you are absolutely right being anxious. gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/31/intro-to-rebase.html **Pro tip:** before doing rebase, do a `git tag thiswasmystate`. If you totally shoot yourself into the foot with rebase, do `git reset --hard thiswasmystate` and you have your original state again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of this problem actually has to do with the fact your fork of libgdx has the changes done in your master branch. Ideally the work for a pull request should be done in a "feature" or "topic" branch in Git:

1. Fork the main libgdx repository
2. Clone your fork, and add a remote called "upstream" that points to the original repository:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/snovak/libgdx.git
   cd libgdx
   git remote add upstream https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx.git
   ```
3. Create a new topic branch off of your master:

   ```
   git checkout -b android_gyroscope_implementation master
   ```
4. Do the work, and make any number of commits
5. Rebase your commits on new changes from the "upstream" fork:

   ```
   git fetch upstream

   # Keep your commits
   git rebase upstream/master

   # "Squash" your commits interactively to summarize your work
   git rebase -i upstream/master
   ```
6. Push your changes to your fork when you are ready for the pull request

   ```
   # The first time
   git push origin -u android_gyroscope_implementation

   # Subsequent pushes just need:
   git push origin HEAD
   ```
7. Submit your pull request
8. From this point on, just merge `upstream/master` into the android_gyroscope_implementation to maintain history.
9. The maintainer of the original repository can do a `git merge --squash` or before the final merge, you can do another `git rebase -i upstream/master` and squash all of your commits into one.

Comment: I'm going to try this today!  Thanks for the help @greg-burghardt !

Comment: This helped a lot.  I've learned a lot more about remotes branches and general git workflow.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding how rebase works.

What rebase is, in essence, is a way to simplify cherry-picking a significant amount of commits and if necessary modifying them.

What happens when you run `git rebase -i master` on your feature branch is the following (strongly simplified version):

1. Git finds the differences between master and your branch, iow. All commits in your branch, that are **not in master**.
2. Git chronologically lists these commits for you to change their order, pick, squash, reword or discard.
3. Upon confirming how you want your commits ordered, sqashed, ..., git will open a queue that performs the operations required.
4. Git will work through the queue with following "alorithm"

   - It takes the next item, cherry-picks the commit specified *onto an intermediate branch* (probably a detached HEAD, actually).
   - **If there are conflicts** Git stops the queue and allows you to resolve these conflicts. When resolving conflicts you can either `--abort` the rebase or `--continue` it. When aborting, git restores the original repository state by discarding the changes made and clears the queue.
   - When continuing, git will continue working the queue, go to the top of the algorithm.

   As soon as the rebase is finished, git labels the current HEAD, which includes all the changes in your branch, but as descendants of `master` with the branch you started on and discards the old branch.

In this whole process git will **not** try to take commits that are *already in the target branch* so your worries are not necessary :)

Comment: I'm going to have to read this a few times to "get it".  The last line is comforting!  :-)  Thanks for the thorough explanation!